# How do I return to a calling activity if the user presses BACK?

Tags: android, android-activity

My MAIN activity is spawning a child activity that contains a `ListView`.  While this `ListView` is being populated (through an `AsyncTask`), an indeterminate progress bar is shown.

However, assuming that I am an impatient user and I press the BACK button, the progress bar is cancelled but I am left with a blank screen. I have to press BACK one more time to go back to the MAIN activity.

I would like the app to go back directly to the MAIN activity by pressing BACK only once. Can somebody point me in the right direction?  I am thinking I should call `finish()` somewhere but I don't know where to put it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`setOnCancelListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setOnCancelListener(android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener)) on Dialog (which ProgressDialog extends).

Comment: what actually it's doing,suppose i'm in new activity where i use the this function.

Comment: Hi @MGSenthil, can you explain more? I don't think I understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this,place this code in your activities oncreate block.

```
findViewById(R.id.back).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        finish();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: I am not using an icon as a back button though, I was referring to the BACK button on the handset in my question.

Answer (score 0):

you should override "onBackPressed()" 
it will call when the activity has detected the user's press of the back key.

```
@override
 public void onBackPressed(){
   this.startActivity(this,MainActivity.class);
 }
```

this code will call the MainActivity when emulator/ipphone back button pressed...